# How can I coalesce this dataset in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, coalesce

I am an ICU physician conducting research which involves taking lots of patient-related data from the ICU computer system (all ethically approved, etc). As is often the case, getting data out then requires cleaning and wrangling before it can be used properly.

I have obtained a set of data, and have wrangled it as best I can. Of course, my data science skills are pretty rudimentary and despite being an enthusiastic R user, I am at a complete blockage, and am hoping some of you might be able to shed some light on my problem and how to solve it. I absolutely cannot get round this, but suspect it is a commonly encountered issue in time-series work.

At present, my dataset now includes multiple rows for each time point. So, at time X there is an individual row for heart rate, blood pressure, etc. There are 46 observations, and this repeats for every time point (344 in total for this patient). All observations are not recorded at each time point. I have provided a link to screenshots of the way this data is arranged [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCy40.jpg).

A sample of the data is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LY-yZQnJQRL1ZUhj-TQYSRyba6-kcx5X/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115892245518467478896&rtpof=true&sd=true), is that helps.

The best progress I've made is with the following nested for-loop structure. It works for the first set of observations. I have tried a strange while-loop arrangement that fell flat on its face.

```
# First, add a group to the entire table specifying each time point that 
# observations were conducted. 
Patient_full$Verification_group <- as.numeric(as.factor(Patient_full$Time))

# Get the number of these groups
observation_times <- max(Patient_full$Verification_group)

# Create the bare bones of an overall table. This is the first row of the table.
patient_obs_final <-  Patient_full[1,]

# Next I need to create a loop within loop. The master loop will coerce rows
# that have been created by the sub-loop.
for (i in 1 : observation_times) {
  
  # Isolate the overall observation group you are dealing with
  veri_group <- filter(Patient_full, Verification_group == i)

  # Start by getting some numbers to run the sub-loop
  lowest_obs_time_row <- min(veri_group$Row)
  highest_obs_time_row <- max(veri_group$Row)
  rows_in_obs_time <- (highest_obs_time_row - lowest_obs_time_row)
  
  # We can run the sub-loop now
  obs_at_timepoint <- Patient_full[lowest_obs_time_row, ]
  for (j in 1 : (rows_in_obs_time - 1)) {
    obs_at_timepoint <- coalesce(obs_at_timepoint, Patient_full[j + 1,])
    
  }
  
  patient_obs_final <-  rbind(patient_obs_final, obs_at_timepoint)
  
}

patient_obs_final
```

As soon as j goes to 2 the thing seems to fall apart.

So, in the end my goal is to have a separate row for each time point, and for that row to have whatever was recorded/observed at that time. I am at a loss, and can't even tell why my solution isn't working. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Typically it makes it easier for other people to answer your question if you paste the output of ``dput(dat)`` into your question so people can reproduce your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it in a loop. Only one `summarise_at` is enough !!

```
library(tidyverse)
Patient_01_sample <- read.csv("E:/R/StackOverflow/Patient_01_sample.xlsx - Sheet 1.csv", row.names=1)
f = function(x) ifelse(length(x[!is.na(x)])==0,NA,x[!is.na(x)][1]) 
Patient = read_csv("Patient_01_sample.xlsx - Sheet 1.csv")
Patient %>% group_by(Time) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(3:45), f)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 44
  Time                `Glucose ABG` `Lactate ABG` PaCO2  PaO2 `PH (ABG)` `Potassium ABG` `Sodium ABG` `Cardiac Rhythm` `Arterial Pressure Di~
  <dttm>                      <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>                             <dbl>
1 2017-09-04 17:00:00          11.8          10.7  4.42  31.5       7.25             3.9          3.9 ST                                   NA
2 2017-09-04 17:55:00          NA            NA   NA     NA        NA               NA           NA   NA                                   54
3 2017-09-04 18:00:00          NA            NA   NA     NA        NA               NA           NA   ST                                   60
4 2017-09-04 19:00:00          10.1           9.7  4.22  15         7.3              3.9          3.9 ST                                   58
5 2017-09-04 20:00:00           8.1           7.2  5.07  16.9       7.27             3.9          3.9 ST                                   62
# ... with 34 more variables: Arterial Pressure Mean <dbl>, Arterial Pressure Systolic <dbl>, Heart Rate <dbl>,
#   Non Invasive Arterial Pressure Diastolic <dbl>, Non Invasive Arterial Pressure Mean <dbl>,
#   Non Invasive Arterial Pressure Systolic <dbl>, Tympanic Temperature <dbl>, Patient Positioning ABG <lgl>, Central Venous Pressure <lgl>,
#   Delivered Percent O2 <lgl>, Mean Airway Pressure S <lgl>, Minute Volume expired (S) <lgl>, Peak Inspiratory Pressure measured  S <lgl>,
#   Positive End Expiratory pressure <lgl>, S Expired Tidal vol. (breath) <lgl>, S Tidal Volume Inspired <lgl>, Servo i Modes <lgl>,
#   Set FiO2 <lgl>, Set Flow Trigger S <lgl>, Set Pause time % <lgl>, Set PEEP Servo <lgl>, Set rate (CMV or SIMV) <lgl>,
#   Set Tidal Volume (servo) <lgl>, Set Upper Pressure Limit <lgl>, Spontaneous Rate  S <lgl>, Cardiac output (Vigileo) <lgl>, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  mutate(
    Cardiac.Rhythm = if_else(nzchar(Cardiac.Rhythm), Cardiac.Rhythm, NA_character_), 
    across(-Row, ~ .[order(is.na(.))])
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(rowSums(!is.na(.)) > 2) %>%
  as.data.frame()
#   Row                Time Base.excess..vt. Glucose.ABG Lactate.ABG PaCO2 PaO2 PH..ABG. Potassium.ABG Sodium.ABG Cardiac.Rhythm Arterial.Pressure.Diastolic Arterial.Pressure.Mean Arterial.Pressure.Systolic Heart.Rate
# 1   1 2017-09-04 17:00:00            -11.4        11.8        10.7  4.42 31.5     7.25           3.9        3.9             ST                          NA                     NA                         NA         NA
# 2  10 2017-09-04 17:55:00               NA          NA          NA    NA   NA       NA            NA         NA           <NA>                          54                     68                         92        123
# 3  14 2017-09-04 18:00:00               NA          NA          NA    NA   NA       NA            NA         NA             ST                          60                     71                         86        123
# 4  23 2017-09-04 19:00:00             -9.3        10.1         9.7  4.22 15.0     7.30           3.9        3.9             ST                          58                     70                         92        122
# 5  36 2017-09-04 20:00:00             -8.4         8.1         7.2  5.07 16.9     7.27           3.9        3.9             ST                          62                     80                        117         NA
```

(I truncated the columns pasted here ...)

Walk-through:

- For some reason, `Cardiac.Rhythm` has empty strings instead of `NA`, the first mutate converts empty strings `""` to `NA` so that later filtering works;
- `.[order(is.na(.))]` orders the non-`NA` data first within each column;
- `rowSums(.)` ensures that we have at least one non-`NA` datum on a row (the `> 2` takes into account that `Row` and `Time` are not `NA`).

Notes:

- I assume that data is one "person" per frame; if you have a patient id in the data, make sure to add it within the `group_by(.)` as well.
- Within a particular `Time` (and `Patient_ID`, if present), I assume that the order of rows is not important (ergo the per-column reordering of values).
- I do *not* assume that each column can have only one value per `Time`; while logically it makes sense that this would be the case, there could also be an error in the data-scraping/aggregation before this point, so I intentionally do not assume that `x[!is.na(x)]` (when grouped by `Time`) will always return length 1. This will evidence as two (or more) rows in a specific `Time`.
- I thought about using `pivot_longer` for this, and it still might be possible, but ... you have both `numeric` and `character` data here, so it's a little problematic to sort that out *well*.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Row = 1:47, Time = c("2017-09-04 17:00:00", "2017-09-04 17:00:00", "2017-09-04 17:00:00", "2017-09-04 17:00:00", "2017-09-04 17:00:00", "2017-09-04 17:00:00", "2017-09-04 17:00:00", "2017-09-04 17:00:00", "2017-09-04 17:00:00", "2017-09-04 17:55:00", "2017-09-04 17:55:00", "2017-09-04 17:55:00", "2017-09-04 17:55:00", "2017-09-04 18:00:00", "2017-09-04 18:00:00", "2017-09-04 18:00:00", "2017-09-04 18:00:00", "2017-09-04 18:00:00", "2017-09-04 18:00:00", "2017-09-04 18:00:00", "2017-09-04 18:00:00", "2017-09-04 18:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 19:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00", "2017-09-04 20:00:00" ), Base.excess..vt. = c(-11.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -9.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -8.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Glucose.ABG = c(NA, 11.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Lactate.ABG = c(NA, NA, 10.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), PaCO2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 4.42, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.22, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.07, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), PaO2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 31.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), PH..ABG. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.25, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.27, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Potassium.ABG = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Sodium.ABG = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Cardiac.Rhythm = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "ST", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "ST", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "ST", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "ST"), Arterial.Pressure.Diastolic = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 54L, NA, NA, NA, 60L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 58L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 62L, NA, NA, NA), Arterial.Pressure.Mean = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 68L, NA, NA, NA, 71L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 70L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 80L, NA, NA), Arterial.Pressure.Systolic = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 92L, NA, NA, NA, 86L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 92L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 117L, NA ), Heart.Rate = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 123L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 123L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 122L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Non.Invasive.Arterial.Pressure.Diastolic = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 58L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Non.Invasive.Arterial.Pressure.Mean = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 71L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Non.Invasive.Arterial.Pressure.Systolic = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 108L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Tympanic.Temperature = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 37.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Patient.Positioning.ABG = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Central.Venous.Pressure = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Delivered.Percent.O2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Mean.Airway.Pressure.S = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Minute.Volume.expired..S. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Peak.Inspiratory.Pressure.measured..S = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Positive.End.Expiratory.pressure = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), S.Expired.Tidal.vol...breath. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), S.Tidal.Volume.Inspired = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Servo.i.Modes = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Set.FiO2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Set.Flow.Trigger.S = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA ), Set.Pause.time.. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Set.PEEP.Servo = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA ), Set.rate..CMV.or.SIMV. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Set.Tidal.Volume..servo. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Set.Upper.Pressure.Limit = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Spontaneous.Rate..S = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Cardiac.output..Vigileo. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DO2.Vigileo. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DO2I.Vigileo. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Stroke.Volume.Index.Vigileo. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Stroke.Volume.Vigileo. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Systemic.Vascular.Resistance.Index.Vigileo. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Systemic.Vascular.Resistance.Vigileo. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Ionised.Calcium.ABG = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Set.Pressure.Control.level.above.PEEP.S. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -47L))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'll be honest, the way you have done this is a step above my understanding and I can't implement it specifically yet. I will keep trying!

Comment: Odd that it is causing problems, this was done on your advertised dataset with no errors/warnings and produces those 5 rows of resulting data.

Comment: Oh I believe you, the problem lies with me. I believe I am operating at a very basic level that when I see what you have done it isn't clicking for me. When it comes to data wrangling I am still operating a really basic level, despite my enthusiasm to get it right!

Comment: Can I ask a really simple question? What tool did you use to read in my data?

Comment: I went to your link, then highlighted the data and copied, then in my R ran something like `read.delim(text = paste(readClipboard(), collapse = "\r\n"), as.is=TRUE, header=TRUE)` (give or take, I have a helper-function do most of it for me).

Comment: Hey, I got it working. Thanks for taking the time to show me the solution to this. It is much appreciated. I'm in Ireland so I owe you a Guinness if you find yourself out my way! Thank you

Comment: And one final question; when I run your code, the only difference I get is that the time values are all items such as '42982.70833'. I have tried coercing them as POSIXct values, but that doesn't seem to do it. Do you know why that would be happening?

Comment: That looks like a `Date`-class object numerified. That is, `as.Date(42982.70833, origin="1900-01-01")` returns `"2017-09-06"` (as a `Date`-class object). However, given the data I copied, nothing looks date-like, time `Time` which looks like a proper timestamp (not date-stamp).

Answer (score 0):

As @r2evans pointed out, this cal also be done with `dplyr::pivot_wider`.
As he suggested, we need a little hack, that is, to transform all columns to character, then back to their original classes after changing back to wide with `pivot_wider`

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

df<-read.xlsx("Patient_01_sample.xlsx")

df %>% mutate(`Cardiac Rhythm`=replace(`Cardiac Rhythm`, `Cardiac Rhythm`=='', NA)) %>%
        select(-1) %>%
        mutate(across(-1, as.character)) %>%
        pivot_longer(-1)%>%
        group_by(name) %>%
        filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
        ungroup%>%
        pivot_wider(id_cols=Time) %>%
        mutate(across(-c(1, `Cardiac Rhythm`), as.numeric))

# A tibble: 5 x 18
  Time                `Base excess (vt)` `Glucose ABG` `Lactate ABG` PaCO2  PaO2 `PH (ABG)` `Potassium ABG`
  <dttm>                           <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl>
1 2017-09-04 17:00:00              -11.4          11.8          10.7  4.42  31.5       7.25             3.9
2 2017-09-04 17:55:00               NA            NA            NA   NA     NA        NA               NA  
3 2017-09-04 18:00:00               NA            NA            NA   NA     NA        NA               NA  
4 2017-09-04 19:00:00               -9.3          10.1           9.7  4.22  15         7.3              3.9
5 2017-09-04 20:00:00               -8.4           8.1           7.2  5.07  16.9       7.27             3.9
# … with 10 more variables: Sodium ABG <dbl>, Cardiac Rhythm <chr>, Arterial Pressure Diastolic <dbl>,
#   Arterial Pressure Mean <dbl>, Arterial Pressure Systolic <dbl>, Heart Rate <dbl>,
#   Non Invasive Arterial Pressure Diastolic <dbl>, Non Invasive Arterial Pressure Mean <dbl>,
#   Non Invasive Arterial Pressure Systolic <dbl>, Tympanic Temperature <dbl>
```